# Can't merge the standard and error log in PM2

Tags: logging, pm2

I'm trying to have one file where all the log is saved, so I'm starting my app using

```
pm2 start app --merge-logs -l --log "~/webapps/infranodus/infranodus/infralogpm2.log"
```

the app starts but there's nothing in the file, only the standard logs are created.

i tried to `touch` create the file but that doesn't help either.

Comment: are using cluster or single instance ?

Comment: Single instance

Comment: according to this comment https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/337#issuecomment-40677868 merge works only for instances and also what i saw in the help `merge logs from different instances` so for a single instance i think will be better to write it in bash

Comment: what do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried few checks on RHEL 7.4 using NodeJS 10.15 and PM2 3.2.4 and following HelloWorld ExpressJS code.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // Send the HTTP header 
    // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
    // Content Type: text/plain
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // Send the response body as "Hello World"
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
console.error('This is on STDERR');
```

Assuming above code is within `./bin/app2` file, and required modules are present under `node_modules`,

I ran application as `pm2 start ./bin/app2 --merge-logs -l --log /var/tmp/sample-app2.log` and other combinations described below.

1. `--merge-logs` is not desired for a single instance. As per `pm2 --help`, it says "merge logs from different instances but keep error and out separated". Though in my case, STDOUT and STDERR, both appeared in desired log file, with and without `--merge-logs` option.
2. `-l` and `--log` both should not be used. Ideally, you should have used only one of it as per Unix command line argument conventions. However, in my case, it worked the way you have suggested as well as only with `--log`.
3. As part of counter check, ran `pm2 start ./bin/app2 --output /var/tmp/sample-app2-stdout.log --error /var/tmp/sample-app2-error.log`. It generates two files with output from `console.log` and `console.error` respectively.

In your case, I suggest you check that adequate disk space is available on partition where log file is stored, and do `pm2 delete app` and then try again.

If that does not resolve issue, is it possible to share a sample code and exact steps to reproduce a problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The key thing was to do `pm2 delete app` and restart it with the `--log` parameter without using the `--merge-logs`